# How to load one image at a time?

Tags: android

I have a form with 10 images which need to be downloaded from my server. The problem I have is that when the form is displayed, the library I'm using will start downloading all 10 images at the same time causing some of the image download requests to time out. (I don't know why it does)

So I think I could fix this by changing my code to download one image at a time.

Is my understanding correct in that I should treat each of the image download request as an Async task and chain them together so that only one image download request will be processed at a time?

Any libraries I should look into to save time in implementing this? Or any other techniques I should be aware of?

Comment: The android developers site shows the [AsyncTask Example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on how to download files, you can just change it to what you need. Same idea though

Comment: @derek Is my approach correct though?

Comment: You don't need multi AsynTasks, you will just need one and chain all the files for it to download, then it will do them 1 at a time

Comment: I agree just one task. Then I hope I can just pass the UI elements to populate each downloaded image to the respective UI element.

Comment: Yes in the `onPostExecute()` `onPreExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()` all can interact with the UI

Comment: @Derek if you would be so kind to repost your comments as an answer, I will accept it as the answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from the comments I had to this question.

You can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You can update the ui when each has finished in the functions:

`onPostExecute() 
onPreExecute()
onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

you can try Image loading lib `Glide`. You can set priorities for image loading so this can be achieved using Glide.
Here is [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)